# Snowflake SQL compilation for a stored procedure creating a TASK with block statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to come up with a SP that creates a certain task, appended by year, for a generic approach.
I can create the tasks outside, alone, with the $$ marks,
but I can't do it inside JS SP like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_exec_tasks_by_year_range()
RETURNS varchar
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
$$
    var return_value = "";
    var range_years = Array.from(Array(new Date().getUTCFullYear() - 2006), (_, i) => (i + 2007).toString());
    //CREATE a task TO CALL SP BY YEAR, FROM 2007-current year
    range_years.forEach((year_elem) => {
        rs = snowflake.createStatement( { 
        sqlText: `CREATE OR REPLACE TASK MY_TSK_YEAR_`+year_elem+`
        SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 30 22 * * SUN UTC'
        AS 
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
        $$
        DECLARE
            year_track float;
            rs resultset;
          BEGIN
            year_track := :1;
            rs := (execute IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(?)' using (year_track));
            return TABLE(rs);
         END;
         $$
         ;`
        , binds: [year_elem] }).execute();
        rs.next();
        //rs.getColumnValue(1);
        return_value += "MY_TSK_YEAR_"+year_elem+", ";
        
        to_exec = snowflake.createStatement( { 
        sqlText: `EXECUTE TASK MY_TSK_YEAR_`+year_elem+`
        to_exec.next();
        return_value += to_exec.getColumnValue(1)+", "; 
    });
    

    return return_value;
$$;
```

because it throws me

```
syntax error line ...at position 2 unexpected 'DECLARE'
```

while creating the TASK manually, works, because I don't have a conflict between $$?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK SHARED.SRC_EXT_WEATHER.TSK_DUMMY
SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 30 22 * * SUN UTC'
AS   
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  $$
  DECLARE
    year_track float;
    rs resultset;
  BEGIN
    year_track := 2007;
    rs := (execute IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(?)' using (year_track));
    return TABLE(rs);
  END;
  $$;
```

Is it possible to make the SP to work for the TASK created with EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE block and bind parameter? The problem seems to be the way I write in inside the $$ scope of the stored procedure, no?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using the $$ string terminator for the stored procedure. Then inside the body of the stored procedure you're using $$ to terminate the string containing the body of the task. As soon as the compiler runs into that, it sees it as the end of the string defining the stored procedure body. To use $$ in the body of a stored procedure, you can do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_exec_tasks_by_year_range()
RETURNS varchar
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
$$
    const double_dollar = '$' + '$';
    var return_value = "";
    var to_exec;
    var rs_exec;
    var range_years = Array.from(Array(new Date().getUTCFullYear() - 2006), (_, i) => (i + 2007).toString());
    //CREATE a task TO CALL SP BY YEAR, FROM 2007-current year
    range_years.forEach((year_elem) => {
        rs = snowflake.createStatement( { 
        sqlText: `CREATE OR REPLACE TASK MY_TSK_YEAR_${year_elem}
        WAREHOUSE = MOS_WEATHER
        SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 30 22 * * SUN UTC'
        AS 
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
        ${double_dollar}
        DECLARE
            year_track float;
            rs resultset;
          BEGIN
            year_track := :1;
            rs := (execute IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(?)' using (year_track));
            return TABLE(rs);
         END;
         ${double_dollar};`
        , binds: [year_elem] }).execute();
        rs.next();
        //rs.getColumnValue(1);
        return_value += "MY_TSK_YEAR_"+year_elem+", ";
        
        to_exec = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `EXECUTE TASK MY_TSK_YEAR_${year_elem}`});
        rs_exec = to_exec.execute();
        rs_exec.next();
        return_value += rs_exec.getColumnValue(1)+", "; 
    });
    

    return return_value;
$$;
```

Comment: Hi Greg. Ok, I've tried yor suggestion but it seems now it behaves like a parameter, so when I run the procedure, it asks me for double_dolar, and then it returns:

SQL Error [100132] [P0000]: JavaScript execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in create_exec_tasks_by_year_range at ' const double_dollar = $ + $;' position 23
can you help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I edited my answer. You can try it now. Getting past the $$ error exposed various other errors. I corrected them for you and ran the SP okay on my side. There were some syntax errors and attempt to use a statement object like a resultset object. Should be okay now.

Comment: Hi again, Greg I did try like that, and remove the last part of to_Exec either, just to try, but I still get: QL Error [1003] [42000]: Execution error in store procedure CREATE_EXEC_TASKS_BY_YEAR_RANGE:
SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 7 at position 8 unexpected 'DECLARE'.
At Statement.execute, line 24 position 32
Array.forEach, line 8 position 16

Comment: It's running for me. If you copy & paste the edited version of the code it should work.

Comment: I was running on DBeaver and it wasn't throwing that error (I don't remeber what exactly changes in Dbeaver, but I would like to understand). I ran the exact code and called the SP on snowflake console, but once each task runs, they fail with SQL compilation error: error line 6 at position 26
invalid identifier '1', so :1 is not being recognized either?

Comment: Go to the History tab in the Snowflake UI and examine the tasks that the SP is building. Extract the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE portion and try to run it. There is a bind variable, but nothing binding to it. This is a confusing point in the documentation for EXECUTE IMMEDIATE that I have informed the docs team and that they are working to correct. You cannot bind a variable that way.

Comment: If you can't get this working, please send your SE an email referencing this question and have him/her reach out to me. We can get this working. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Greg , yes the execute IMMEDIATE with the USING for binding seems to be not working. I usually check via SQL commands for the task_history. But I don't know how to check what gets executed/translated INSIDE the task procedure ...can you please guide me there? I would really like to know how can I put this to work :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249525/discussion-between-greg-pavlik-and-nevermind).

Answer (score 0):

[@Greg Pavlik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12756381/greg-pavlik) I don't know my final approach is OK, but it's working, as far as I run this on SF UI!

The above code, for me worked with a minor change from :1 to ${year_elem} , but then I face issue with **binding a string value** (single quoted) ... like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_exec_tasks_by_year_range(str_arg string)
RETURNS varchar
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
COMMENT ='[DRAFT] SP that creates tasks since a certain rangw with exec immediate block using 2 args: one is year in range, other is a string to isnert as well'
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
$$
    const double_dollar = '$' + '$';
    var return_value = "";
    var to_exec;
    var rs_exec;
    var arg = STR_ARG;
    var range_years = Array.from(Array(new Date().getUTCFullYear() - 2020), (_, i) => (i + 2021).toString());
    //CREATE a task TO CALL SP BY YEAR, FROM 2007-current year
    range_years.forEach((year_elem) => {
        rs = snowflake.createStatement( { 
        sqlText: `CREATE OR REPLACE TASK MY_TSK_YEAR_${year_elem}
        SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 30 22 * * SUN UTC'
        AS 
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
        ${double_dollar}
        DECLARE
            year_track float;
            rs resultset;
            my_str varchar;
          BEGIN
            year_track := ${year_elem};
            my_str:= ${arg} ;
            rs := (execute IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO Z_TEST_TASK_INSERT2 VALUES(?,?)' using (year_track,my_str));
            return TABLE(rs);
         END;
         ${double_dollar};`
        //, binds: [year_elem] 
       }).execute();
        rs.next();
        return_value += rs.getColumnValue(1);        
    });
    
    return return_value;
$$;

    CALL create_exec_tasks_by_year_range('testing_String');
    EXECUTE TASK MY_TSK_YEAR_2021;
    EXECUTE TASK MY_TSK_YEAR_2022;

000904  SQL compilation error: error line 8 at position 21
invalid identifier 'testing_String'
```

One thing I would like to understand is:

- How to use bind variable as a single quoted string? How to escape it or at leats distinguish it from the query prefixed by ' alread?
- The SP creation succeeds via SQL Editor (DBEaver for instance) or SF UI
- *But* the CALL  is only working for me on SF UI (and SNOWSQL must happen the same, I assume). Is that something to do with the drivers used by JDBC vs. SF UI?